# Windows Mobile 6.0/6.5 - Push Notification

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-mobile, compact-framework, push-notification

My mobile application needs to ping web service (WCF) periodically to get the latest data from server. The problem is, this is done periodically even if there isn't anything new on the server. Is there any way that Server notifies device about the change? Like Push Notification? I have read that Push Notifications can be done by SMS and Email. But, both has disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with long lived HTTP requests...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446486.aspx

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I already looked at it before posting here. I don't think that the above method is using Push Notification. It is also listening to the changes continuously. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, it uses long lived polling, that is, it opens an http connection that is not closed, and handles the data that the server is sending back con that connection whenever there is new data, so it is push in that sense. By the way, it is the same technique used by the Exchange ActiveSync protocol. If you use exchange, you could piggyback on that same protocol for your application.